# React Component state value not updated, when setState is called on jsonObject's property

Tags: reactjs, web-frontend

I am working on three properties of JSON object which returns boolean values.

```
updateChange=(value) =>{
    //Making copy of existing json Object
    let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.mainValue));
    // chaning property of cellular over here
    newState.cellular = value;
    console.log(newState);
    this.setState({mainValue:newState});

    //I tried setState in many different ways. But Component is not changing state value 

    console.log(this.state.mainValue)
};
```

I found why this is happening. I am using `getDerivedStateFromProps` in this component to look at changes made by parent to update values. This is avoiding changes made to state of the child. So I have created a state called previous state to compare the previous props and present props from parent to render. This avoids component to refresh when ever it local state values changes.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(propsnow,state){

  if(state.previous !== propsnow.detailSwitches){
   return{
        previous :propsnow.detailSwitches,
        cellular: propsnow.detailSwitches.cellular,
        wifi1: propsnow.detailSwitches.wifi1,
        wifi2: propsnow.detailSwitches.wifi2
   };

    }
    return null;
 }
```

Any examples or better practices can be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Please do `console.log` in render before and after `setState` and provide the output.

Comment: {id: "123", wifi1: true, wifi2: false, cellular: true}//before
 {id: "123", wifi1: true, wifi2: false, cellular: true}//after

Comment: How does the component should be rerendered? Ad the states are the same.

Comment: Exactly state is not at all changing. I tried using individual json  properties as state values then it worked. But when i use it this way, state is not at all changing.

Answer (score 0):

You are ONLY setting the 'mainValue' variable of your state to the value of  newstate, shouldn't you be updating the whole state?

```
this.setState({...newState})
```

Comment: But I am sending these values as a props for child component like this {this.state.mainValue.cellular}.

Comment: can you show us your state is and what newState holds?

Comment: this.state={
   mainValue :props.detailSwitches
   
  }                                                                                                                             new State values are like this. {id: "123", wifi1: true, wifi2: false, cellular: false} after value is set on cellular.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    mainValue: {
       ...prevState.mainValue,
      cellular: value
  }}))
```

It is an immutable way to update state.

Comment: I did but still it's not changing the state of object.

Comment: Did you use shouldComponentUpdate ? For example, if you have something like this if(this.state.mainVlaue !== nextState.mainValue) { return true } then it can be a problem